# Checking the same objects's order in lists/Python

Tags: python

I want to check if the list1 is a sublist to list2 **in the same order**. The most important thing is that objects must be in the same sequence.

For Examples, these are two list:

```
list1=[1,2,3]
list2=[8,9,1,2,3,6,5]
```

which should give me True when checked,because objects 1,2 nad 3 are in the same sequence in list1 as in list2.

In other side:

```
list1=[2,3,1]
list2=[1,2,3]
```

This should give me False as the order is not the same in list2.

So far I have made that:

```
def sublist(list1,list2):
    s1=" ".join(str(i) for i in list1)
    s2=" ".join(str(i) for i in list2)
    if s1 in s2:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code so far?

Comment: I didn't get it what your questions is all about? Are you asking for some other method?

Comment: That works. What is the question?

Comment: That i can't check when the objects aren't in the same order,i gave an example up.

Comment: Can you add more explanation to it? Why your code fails?

Comment: Im asking how can i change that code which only output when objects's order is the same. For example l=[1,2,3] and l2=[1,2,3,4],the order is the same but in l3=[2,1,3] and l4=[1,2,3],it is not.

Comment: By converting them into strings, you already guarantee that the order has to be the same.

Comment: does this helps: https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/list/python-data-type-list-exercise-32.php?

Comment: Ok,That's makes sense,thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

A straight forward solution would be

```
def sublist(list1, list2):
    for i in range(len(list2)-len(list1)):
        if list2[i:i+len(list1)] == list1:
            return i, True
        else:
            return -1, False
```

returning also the index of the potential match or -1 otherwise.

Comment: You can return anything else that is supposed to indicate the list is not present as a sublist, it just should not be anything that could be mixed up with a valid index. Using -1 for this is not too uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1=[1,2,3]
list2=[8,9,1,2,3,6,5]

def list_in_list(l1,l2):
    return_val = False
    for i in range(len(list2)):
        if list1 == list2[i:i+len(list1)]:
            return_val=True
        continue
    return return_val

list_in_list(list1,list2)
True
```

Comment: SO doesn't tolerate code only answers.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine

Indentation was wrong other-wise even for the case given it gives correct answer

```
list1=[2,3,1]
list2=[1,2,3]
def sublist(list1,list2):
    s1=" ".join(str(i) for i in list1)
    s2=" ".join(str(i) for i in list2)
    if s1 in s2:
        return True
    else:
        return False
sublist(list1,list2)
```

[image]

Comment: The OP's indentation should've been fine, it was a matter of formatting.